# selector in .on() is not respected

Tags: jquery, ajax

jQuery code for Ajax Form:

```
$(document).on('submit', $('.ajaxForm'), function (e) { // only the element with class ajaxForm
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form which has the class ajaxForm
});
```

1. Form - 1 with class `ajaxForm`

`<form action='_ACTION_' class='ajaxForm'><input type='submit'></form>`

2. Form - 2 **without** class `ajaxForm`

`<form action='_ACTION_' method='get'><input type='submit'></form>`

The form 1 works as expected but the form 2 must be submitted in traditional way such as the new URL must be `_ACTION_?param=value`, but this form too is being submitted as Ajax Form. Is there any mistake in jQuery part?

Though both are same I tried as `$('form.ajaxForm')` too, but no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the signature of the [.on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

your selector should be a *string* (not a wrapped jquery set of nodes):

```
$(document).on('submit', '.ajaxForm', function (e) { // only the element with class ajaxForm
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form which has the class ajaxForm
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Though sweaver2112 is totally right that the selector must be a string (and you're lucky that you can grab `.ajaxForm` with a simple string), there may be situations where you do want to pass an object/variable.

Let's say you wanted to write something like this:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', $('li').has('span'), function(){…}
```

There is a workaround for cases where a string-selector is not an option, and that is to delay the "jQuery complexity" (and then check with an if-query) inside the event with the more general selector: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcu580u3/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
$(document).on('submit', '.ajaxForm', function (e) { // only the element with class ajaxForm
        e.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form which has the class ajaxForm
      console.log("hello");
    });

$("#abc").html('<form class="ajaxForm"><input type="submit"> with ajax</form><form ><input type="submit"> without ajax</form>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="abc"></div>
```

Comment: This works, though I preferred `$(document)` for the reason I don't need to attach when some `ajaxForm` is added dynamically into the DOM.